# What is this half-filled explosion-like icon next to the origin symbol?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

I received a shiny Pokémon through the Surprise Trade, which I presumed as hacked due to the name of the trainer and Pokémon. I've received quite a few of these in the past, so I will take the held item and then store them in my never-to-be-used box.

The Pokémon I received this time had new icon that I had never seen before. I checked all my previous Pokémon, and none of them have it. To my knowledge, I have never seen this icon until the release of Crowned Tundra.

So what is this icon, and what does it mean?
[image: shiny Moltres with new icon]

<sub>I redacted the trainer and Pokémon name because they lead to a website</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [Battle-Ready Symbol](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Origin_mark#Battle-ready_symbol):

> An NPC in the Battle Tower allows the player to give the battle-ready symbol to any of their Pokémon that doesn't already have that symbol or the Galar symbol. The process of doing so also deletes its record of relearnable moves (if any) and replaces its current move set with level-up moves, ensuring that the Pokémon cannot know any moves it could only learn from a previous generation. Beginning with the July 2020 ranking season, Pokémon with this symbol are eligible to participate in ranked ladder and tournament battles as though they were Pokémon that originated in Galar, with the exception of Mythical Pokémon (such as Zeraora) and special Legendary Pokémon (such as Mewtwo).

Essentially, it functions as a symbol showing that the Pokemon is able to participate in official online tournaments.